# How to combine these two functions into one implementation?

Tags: c++

I have this class' dependencies :

```
class Player
{
public:
    struct Unit{
        struct Pos{
            uint_fast16_t x;
            uint_fast16_t y;
        }position;
        uint_fast8_t ship : 1 ;
        uint_fast8_t miss : 1 ;
        uint_fast8_t hit : 1 ;
        uint_fast8_t destroyed : 1;
        uint_fast8_t r: 4;
    };
std::array<Unit,100> battle_field = { state }; //GetSingleUnitState indirectly gets data from this array

const uint_fast8_t Player::makeShot(  const uint_fast16_t size, const uint_fast16_t x, const uint_fast16_t y  )const;
const uint_fast8_t Player::isShip( const uint_fast16_t size, const uint_fast16_t x, const uint_fast16_t y ) const;

const Player::Unit Player::GetSingleUnitState(const uint_fast16_t &Absciss ,const uint_fast16_t &Ordinate) const{
   return this->first_player_battle_field_.battle_field[ ( (Ordinate * 10 ) + Absciss ) ];
};

};
```

There is also a lot of other data but it is not connected to my question.

Below i pasted implementation of both mentioned in declaration methods, they work proper but they are almost the same ( only differs in `unit`'s field which is check) and i do not know how to combine them into 1 method with common parametr because it always depends on `uint_fast8_t tmp,num ;` variables and i can not provide all needed "booleans" before call.

```
const uint_fast8_t Player::isShip( const uint_fast16_t size, const uint_fast16_t x, const uint_fast16_t y ) const{
    if(  ( (x > 0) &&(y > 0)&&( Player::GetPlayerInstance().GetSingleUnitState(x -1 ,y -1).ship  != 0 ))  ||
          ( (y > 0) &&(10 > x)&&  (Player::GetPlayerInstance().GetSingleUnitState(x +1 ,y -1).ship  != 0 )) ||
          ( (10 >y)&&(10 > x)&& (Player::GetPlayerInstance().GetSingleUnitState(x +1 ,y +1).ship  != 0 ))  ||
          ( (x > 0) &&(10 > y)&& ( Player::GetPlayerInstance().GetSingleUnitState(x -1 ,y +1).ship  != 0 ))||
          ( (x > 0) && ( Player::GetPlayerInstance().GetSingleUnitState(x -1 ,y).ship  != 0 ))||
          ( (y > 0 )&&( Player::GetPlayerInstance().GetSingleUnitState(x ,y -1 ).ship != 0 ))
          )
        return false;
    if( ( y > 0 ) &&( Player::GetPlayerInstance().GetSingleUnitState(x ,y -1 ).ship != 0 ) ) return false;
    if( Player::GetPlayerInstance().GetSingleUnitState(x ,y).ship == 0 )return false;
    uint_fast8_t tmp = x,num = 0;
    while( ( Player::GetPlayerInstance().GetSingleUnitState(tmp,y).ship != 0)  &&(  tmp < 10 ) ){
        tmp++,num++;
    }
    if( num == size ){
        if( Player::GetPlayerInstance().GetSingleUnitState(x ,y+1).ship != 0 ) return false;
        return true;
    }
    tmp = y;
    num = 0;
    while( ( Player::GetPlayerInstance().GetSingleUnitState(x ,tmp).ship != 0 ) &&( tmp < 10 ) ) {
        tmp++;
        num++;
    }
    if( num == size ){
        if( Player::GetPlayerInstance().GetSingleUnitState(x+1 ,y).ship != 0 ) return false;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool Player::makeShot(  const uint_fast16_t size, const uint_fast16_t x, const uint_fast16_t y  )const
{
    if(  ( (x > 0) &&(y > 0)&&( Player::GetPlayerInstance().GetSingleUnitState(x -1 ,y -1).hit  != 0 ))  ||
          ( (y > 0) &&(10 > x)&&  (Player::GetPlayerInstance().GetSingleUnitState(x +1 ,y -1).hit  != 0 )) ||
          ( (10 >y)&&(10 > x)&& (Player::GetPlayerInstance().GetSingleUnitState(x +1 ,y +1).hit  != 0 ))  ||
          ( (x > 0) &&(10 > y)&& ( Player::GetPlayerInstance().GetSingleUnitState(x -1 ,y +1).hit  != 0 ))||
          ( (x > 0) && ( Player::GetPlayerInstance().GetSingleUnitState(x -1 ,y).hit  != 0 ))||
          ( (y > 0 )&&( Player::GetPlayerInstance().GetSingleUnitState(x ,y -1 ).hit != 0 ))
          )
        return false;
    if( ( y > 0 ) &&( Player::GetPlayerInstance().GetSingleUnitState(x ,y -1 ).hit != 0 ) ) return false;
    if( Player::GetPlayerInstance().GetSingleUnitState(x ,y).hit == 0 )return false;
    uint_fast8_t tmp = x,num = 0;
    while( ( Player::GetPlayerInstance().GetSingleUnitState(tmp,y).hit != 0)  &&(  tmp < 10 ) ){
        tmp++,num++;
    }
    if( num == size ){
        if( Player::GetPlayerInstance().GetSingleUnitState(x ,y+1).hit != 0 ) return false;
        return true;
    }
    tmp = y;
    num = 0;
    while( ( Player::GetPlayerInstance().GetSingleUnitState(x ,tmp).hit != 0 ) &&( tmp < 10 ) ) {
        tmp++;
        num++;
    }
    if( num == size ){
        if( Player::GetPlayerInstance().GetSingleUnitState(x+1 ,y).hit != 0 ) return false;
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}
```

Comment: You can use a [pointer-to-member](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer) as a parameter to your helper function to pick which field to inspect.

Comment: You declared this const uint_fast8_t Player::makeShot(...) but then the definition is bool Player::makeShot(...) returning a bool? Also if you replace all Player::GetPlayerInstance() by a shorter local variable, it would be more readable.

Comment: Please post a [mre]. What is `Player::GetPlayerInstance()`? Are you allowed to use templates and lambdas?

Comment: @Bob__ it is default GetInstance() singleton method and i am allowed to use templates and lambdas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a template base function to change the member you want to access:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Unit {
    int ship = 1;
    int hit = 2;
};


template <auto member>
void test() {
   Unit unit;
   std::cout << unit.*member << std::endl;
}

int main() {

    test<&Unit::ship>();
    test<&Unit::hit>();

    return 0;
}
```